# Does this make you kafir

Tags: kufr

This hasn’t happened to me but I’m just curious, if someone were to mock Allah in their thoughts would that be considered kafir? Even if the persons intentions wasn’t to disrespect Allah.

Answer (score 0):

"In the Sharia, ‘kufr’ refers to the denial of anything Allah obliges belief in, whatever the Prophet (saw) brought from Allah proven definite and certain; having belief in that with one’s heart that it’s the truth is necessary for one to be a Muslim (believer). Therefore, a person who does not consider any of the definite teachings of the Prophet (saw) to be true or does not approve of them is called a ‘kafir’ (disbeliever).

Having negative thoughts does not amount to Kufr, rather seek Allah (swt) protect you from them and avoid anything that lead to such thoughts. You should instead think of the bounties of Allah for they are not few but many and in abundance...

May Allah protect us from such thoughts.

I suggest you read [this](https://www.islamiqate.com/3998/what-is-the-concept-of-kufr-in-quran%22), it explains the concept of Kufr in Islam.